# geom_bar returning a count of 1

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to plot a bar graph from a data frame. The bar heights are all being returned as 1. Below is a sample of reproducible code:

```
df <- data.frame(country = c("China", "USA", "South Korea"),
                 confirmed = c(4747763, 90, 2060))
ggplot(df, aes(x = country, fill = country)) +
  geom_bar()
```

Why aren't the bar heights matching to the numeric values in the column "confirmed" in my data frame?

Comment: welcome to SO. Please don't forget to accept your own answer once you can do this - so that this question does not appear as unanswered any more! Thanks

Comment: Tried to, but it says I have to wait two days because the answer is my own. But I'll remember to come back!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it. Have to set stat = "identity" to have geom_bar read the y-axis:

```
    df %>%
       ggplot(aes(x = country, y = confirmed)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Comment: as an extra small info - using `geom_col` is the same as `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Comment: great to know that! :)